# GitLab CI/CD cannot authenticate to Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, openid-connect

I set up a IAM role in AWS and saved the ARN as a variable in my GitLab Project.

I have a terraform script that I would like to run via a CI/CD Pipeline using OIDC.

Each time I try to run to the yaml file, it errors on credentials. How can I set the variable in the below pipeline script?

I know it's because there yaml file is not reading the variable file but I can't find anywhere online on how to add the variable into the below script.

```
include:
- template: Terraform/Base.gitlab-ci.yml
- template: Jobs/SAST-IaC.gitlab-ci.yml

default:
id_tokens:
AWS_TOKEN:
aud: https://gitlab.com/


stages:
- validate
- test
- build
- deploy
- cleanup

fmt:
extends: .terraform:fmt
needs: []

validate:
extends: .terraform:validate
needs: []

build:
extends: .terraform:build

variables:
TF_ROOT: Dev

deploy:
extends: .terraform:deploy
dependencies:
- build

environment:
name: $TF_STATE_NAME
```